# MySql Audit Changes from Db Admin, Security

Tags: mysql, security, audit

I know that you can use triggers (before insert, update, delete) to track the changes in history tables. But this only works if the changes are made by the applications.

But in some circumstance, also the database admins will like to make a criminal act and change some database data, in order to to achieve personal benefits.

My question is, how can I protect/audit the database from the changes that can be manually done by the database admins? (They have the full rights over the database)

Comment: It depends a lot on the level of auditing required, but maybe you want to have a look at the MySQL Audit plugins http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/audit-plugins.html like the McAfee Audit plugin for MySQL http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/05/23/experiences-with-the-mcafee-mysql-audit-plugin/ (it is basically a configurable general log)